# How to change X11/Xquartz colour setting to 256 colors Using Bash Script?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, terminal, mac, x11

I want to change X11 color settings from 'From Display'(default) to '256 colors' using Terminal.app.  I already know how to change it using the GUI, but I need a bash script to do it.  I have:

- Mavericks 10.9.5
- XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2)
- MacbookPro

Comment: Can you please share the versions of X11 and the macOS you are using?  The model of computer would be nice too.

Comment: Macos : 10.9.5 Mavericks and X11 : XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2) and Hardware : MacbookPro 15" 2014

Comment: Would you be happy with a bash (or sh) script to do it that simply drives the GUI using osascript(1) to send events to AppleScript?

Comment: I am already using a bash script file to make some other settings, i want to append that file with one or two lines to change the color settings. I don't want to use any ui for now, if no other way to achieve this i may consider using ui. Thanks @D A Vincent

Comment: What process did you use to install XQuartz 2.7.7?  I'm sorry and a bit unhappy to ask.  I've installed various flavours of X11 in the past, but I'm not sure how to do it on 10.9 Mavericks, and how that differs from the computers I have, which have newer versions of macOS.

Comment: In my case i am using XQuartz 2.7.7 to launch an application that will load only in 256 color preferences. So after creating a new user i need to change the display preference of x11 to 256 colors using gui one time per user. I am looking for a script to change the display preferences from 'From Display(default) -> 256 colors' for XQuartz. I install Xquartz using terminal "sudo installer -pkg package_name". Thanks in advance

Comment: I am feeling even more stupid now.  What do I put where you have put "package_name"?  Something I am supposed to have downloaded already?  An installer package?  From the Xquartz project website?

Comment: I'm going to try XQuartz-2.7.11 on this computer with macOS Sierra 10.12.3.  If I understand things properly then perhaps appropriate use of defaults(1) and command line options might work.

Comment: I install Xquartz using terminal "sudo installer -pkg package_name" and package _name is the Xquartz.pkg, i mentioned this just to clear that i installed it through terminal. Sorry if this misled you .Thanks D A Vincent

Comment: Thanks Shaji Kuruvi (how do I make one of those links?), that's a help.  Feeling much less stupid.  

I think I can write you a suitable shell script once I understand how the defaults(1) command works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54337/discussion-between-d-a-vincent-and-shaji-kuruvi).

Comment: Lots of thanks to D A Vincent for helping, Below given solution is working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *command* to change **Color: From Display**, as shown in **X11 Preferences** of **XQuartz**, to
  **Color: 256 Colors**, from the *command line* in **Terminal** is:

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth -int 8
```

- Note: **XQuartz** should be closed when making this change or the ones below, from the *command line* or from within a `bash` *script*.

---

To reset it to the default, **Color: From Display**, use the following:

```
defaults delete org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth
```

Or:

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth -int -1
```

- Note: By default the `depth` *key* doesn't exist however, when reset from the GUI to the default, the setting is `-1`, although either is acceptable to set the default back to **Color: From Display**.

Comment: Thanks to User3439894 for solving my issue, its working from terminal now.Thanks Again.