# How to run XQuartz in 16-bit color mode

Tags: x11, wine, xquartz

Is it possible to run XQuartz in 16-bit color mode on macOS High Sierra?  I tried the suggestions in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274223/how-to-change-x11-xquartz-colour-setting-to-256-colors-using-bash-script) but they didn't seem to work for 16-bit color.

First, I tried setting the color depth in XQuartz preferences:

[image: XQuartz preference pane showing millions of colors]

When I restarted X and checked the color depth using `xwininfo -root` it showed `Depth: 24`.

Next, I tried specifying the color depth inline when starting XQuartz:

```
xquartz -depth 16
```

This caused XQuartz to crash with the error: `Xquartz: start_x11_server: (ipc/mig) server died`

Last, I tried setting the color depth with `defaults`

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 "depth" -int 16
```

This also resulted in a color depth of 24.

However, setting the color mode to **8-bit** using any of the above techniques worked just fine.  XQuartz started up, and `xwininfo -root` showed `Depth: 8`.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  I'm running macOS High Sierra and XQuartz 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4).

**Edit:** I tried with a value of 15, but `xwininfo` is still reporting a color depth of 24.

[image: Output of xwininfo showing 24-bit color depth]

Answer (score 2):

Valid *values* for `"depth"` in `defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 "depth" -int n` where `n` is one of the following:

- From Display: `-1`
- 256 Colors: `8`
- Thousands: `15`
- Millions: `24`

These *values* were obtained using `defaults read org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth` after selecting each of the options in the menu.

[image]

---

Here is the output of the `defaults` (read/write) and `xwininfo -root` *commands*:

```
$ defaults read org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth
24
$ defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 "depth" -int 15
$ defaults read org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth
15
$ xwininfo -root

xwininfo: Window id: 0xf1 (the root window) (has no name)

  Absolute upper-left X:  0
  Absolute upper-left Y:  0
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 2560
  Height: 1418
  Depth: 15
  Visual: 0x22
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x21 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: ForgetGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +0+0  -0+0  -0-0  +0-0
  -geometry 2560x1418+0+0

$
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  How did you find these?  I tried with 15 and 24, and `xwininfo` reported a color depth of 24 for both of them.

Comment: @bonh, I've updated my answer. As you can see when setting `"depth" -int 15` and then running `xwininfo -root` it shows: `Depth: 15`

Comment: Something is fishy.  `defaults read org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 depth` shows 15, the XQuartz preferences shows 'Thousands' but `xwininfo` *still* shows `24`.  What version of macOS/XQuartz are you running?